Давноминулий час у говорах
Добридень! Маю один запит. Чи знає хтось, як утворюють давноминулий час говори, де зберігся перфект, навзір:
|Робив им|
|Робив ись|
|Робив є|
|Робили смо|
|Робили сте|
|Робили суть|
Тепер бо літературна норма творить давноминулий час так:
|Робив був|
|Робила була|
|Робило було|
|Робили були|
Тобто два праслов'янські l-ові дієприкметника.
Чи є яка різниця між оними говорами, та літературною нормою?

Наведіть приклади вжитку в реченні

Не думаю, щоб тут була якась різниця між діалектною і літературною нормою.
Справа в тому, що як перфект, так і плюсквамперфект утворювалися за однією схемою: особова форма дієслова БУТИ (в теперішньому або минулому часі часі) + коротка форма дієприкметника.
Якщо в теперішньому часі БУТИ як зв'язка фактично зникла (тому дієприкметник перебрав на себе функції особової форми), то в минулому зв'язуюча роль залишилася.
Отже вона не відчула на собі таких діалектних змін, як презенс (им, ись, є, смо, суть), а лишилися питомими (був, була, було, були, що, до речі, скоріш суть ті самі дієприкметникові форми).
За доказом можна хоча б звернутися до казок в діалектному виконанні і подивитися, як там реалізовано зачин (жив-був, жила-була, жило-було та жили-були).

Давноминулий час означає дію, що відбувалася перед іншою минулою дією,
тобто одна минула дія передує іншій минулій дії. Утворюються форми
давноминулого часу переважно від дієслів доконаного виду аналітично (до
основного дієслова в минулому часі додається допоміжне дієслово бути в минулому часі в усіх родових формах: прийшов був, прийшла була, прийшло було та у формі множини – прийшли були.
Допоміжне дієслово може бути перед основним дієсловом і після нього, наприклад: Трохи була не втопилась, та жаль було кинуть близняточок ( Т.Шевченко); Я вже зібрався був, та не поїхав через родинні обставини ( О.Довженко).
Ці форми властиві розмовному та художньому стилям, використовуються
рідко не тому, що давноминулий час зникає, а тому, що не так часто виникають ситуації, коли потрібно вжити цей час. Активно в розмовному мовленні використовуються форми давноминулого часу в закарпатських говірках (південно-західний діалект).
У формі давноминулого часу дійсного способу особа виражається синтаксично – через підстановку займенника, оскільки закінчення у формах минулого, давноминулого часу та в умовному способі є родовими.
